# Как структурированно вывести содержимое Excel документа?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, форматирование

Как вывести содержимое Excel файла?
Использую pandas и xlrd.

В ячейках лежат ссылки, довольно длинные. Но выводит почему то не целиком ссылки, а обрезанные (многоточие после ссылки выводит сам PyCharm).

Как полностью вывести содержимое Excel файла?

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile("Links.xlsx")
a = xl.sheet_names
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df.head()
print(df)
```

Вывод:

```
                              https://autoforum.info/ https://dealers.mercedes-benz.ru/ShowRooms?showroom=autoforum
0                          http://www.auto-moscow.ru/                          https://avtoforum.kia.ru/           
1   http://www.auto-moscow.ru/index.php?showforum=...                             https://avtoforum.org/           
2   http://www.auto-moscow.ru/index.php?showforum=...       https://www.facebook.com/mercedes.autoforum/           
3                        https://automania.ru/forums/             https://www.instagram.com/mbautoforum/
```

Содержимое файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При выводе DataFrame на **экран**, Pandas использует параметр `pd.options.display.max_colwidth` для того, чтобы обрезать слишком длинные строки.

NOTE: При сохранении данных в файл (CSV, Excel, etc.), данные обрезаться **не будут**.

Создайте контекст с нужными вам параметрами при выводе на печать:

```
with pd.option_context("display.width", 300, "display.max_colwidth", 200):
    print(df)
```

PS [полный список параметров](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html)